# Bootstrap modal scrolling background on mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm having an interesting issue with bootstrap modal. On desktop it works perfectly, but the issues start when using an iPhone. When you scroll up and down, the background will move instead of the modal, but only if you initially pressed in an input.

It might be an issue that when an input (or a select element) is focused, then the under layer scrolls instead of the modal.

I hope that makes sense.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Comment: hello @edank please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024774/twitter-bootstrap-3-modal-on-mobile-scroll-issues   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965599/bootstrap-3-long-modal-scrolling-background-on-android

Comment: @user00000341, thanks for the link but it was not helpful in my case. They were complaining that the background was moving AS WELL as the modal. In my case, the modal isn't moving at all. Only the background is.

Comment: I am having this _exact_ problem. Background scrolls on modals but ONLY if an input element is first touched. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Here's another SO post with the same question (and no answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403996/bootstrap-3-modal-with-long-form-on-iphone-doesnt-scroll-if-you-touch-input-fie